# Convert GPS coordinates with bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I need to convert to a specific format some gps coordinates which are the output of the exif information of a picture.

This is the typical output:

```
exif:GPSLatitude: 10/1, 10/1, 10/1
exif:GPSLatitudeRef: N
exif:GPSLongitude: 10/1, 10/1, 10/1
exif:GPSLongitudeRef: E
```

and this is the string I need to obtain:

```
10 10 10N 10 10 10E
```

I have been able to do so with the following script:

```
cat $somefile | sed "s/    /$nul/g" | sed "s/exif:GPSLatitudeRef: /$nul/g" | sed "s/exif:GPSLongitude:/$nul/g" | sed "s/exif:GPSLongitudeRef: /$nul/g" | sed "s/exif:GPSLatitude: /$nul/g" | sed "s/\/1/$nul/g" | sed "s/,/$nul/g" | tr -d '\n'
```

However I realised that some pictures have a slightly different output like this:

```
exif:GPSLatitude: 10/1, 10/1, 1099/100
exif:GPSLatitudeRef: N
exif:GPSLongitude: 10/1, 10/1, 1088/100
exif:GPSLongitudeRef: E
```

I understood that the `/1`, `/10` and `/100` (perhaps a `/1000` as well) are denominators of the number before.

Given the following considerations:

1. I don't need a huge accuracy, therefore I can afford to loose the last two decimals of the last number (ie: `1088/100` can become `10` instead of `10.88`);
2. I would like to have that accuracy;
3. I am not totally sure that also the first two numbers of the coordinates (degrees and minutes, ie: `10/1 10/1`) can have decimals. In this case, the accuracy of the coordinates would be totally messed up pointing to a different place in the world.

How can I modify that script (and maybe make it a bit more elegant) to make the calculations and actually substitute a fraction by a number with a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very complex to do this with `sed`. A more suitable tool is `awk` or `bc`.
For example, to use `bc` add another `sed` to convert the input to a sequence of expressions (10/1) and strings (" ") separated by ";" or newline resulting in the following input for bc:

```
10/1;" "; 10/1;" "; 1099/100
"N \n"
10/1;" "; 10/1;" "; 1088/100
"E \n"
```

`bc` will evaluate each expression, and the output will be `10.00 10.00 10.99N 10.00 10.00 10.88E` as you wanted. Here's the sed|bc|tr you need:

```
sed '1i\
scale=2
/Ref: /s/.$/"& \n"/
s/.*: //
s/,/;" ";/g
' | 
bc | tr -d '\n'
```

Alternatively, using `awk` you can replace all your `sed` and `tr` commands with just this:

```
awk '
NF==4 { for(i=2;i<=4;i++){
         split($i,x,"/")
         printf "%s%g",i==2?"":" ",x[1]/x[2]
        }
      }
NF==2 { printf "%s%s",$2,$1~/Lat/?" ":"\n" }'
```

This looks for lines with 4 fields (separated by whitespace) and for fields 2 to 4 splits the field $i (say "1099/100") into 2 parts at the "/" character. It then prints part 1 divided by part 2 (x[1]/x[2]) using the `%g` general format for numbers. The `%s` in the `printf` is replaced by nothing for field 2, and by a space for the other 2 fields. This separates the numbers in the output.

For lines with 2 fields (NF==2) it prints the 2nd field (`$2`) and if field 1 contains the pattern "Lat" it prints a space, else a newline.

Comment: Incredible. I went for the `awk` option as it produces a more clean output (I just found out that degrees and minutes cannot have decimals), only seconds can.